# Adicionando espaços em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso de ajuda nessa questão...

Queremos representar uma escada com altura variável, utilizando um array de strings.

Por exemplo, uma escada com altura 3, representaremos com o seguinte array:

```
var escada3 = [
 "  #",
 " ##",
 "###"
]
```

E uma escada com altura 5, da seguinte forma:

```
var escada5 = [
 "    #",
 "   ##",
 "  ###",
 " ####",
 "#####"
]
```

**Escreva uma função escada que utilize uma altura (um número) e retorne um array que represente a escada correspondente.**

**DICA**
Em JavaScript você pode repetir um texto usando `repeat` da seguinte maneira:

```
var degrau = "#".repeat(2); // agora degrau = "##";
```

Isso servirá para montar nossos degraus;

Mas como faço para inserir a quantidade de degraus de acordo com o número indicado pelo meu array resultado? Como inserir um elemento em um array?

---

Eu consegui resolver parte da questão fazendo as repetições, porém ele quer os espaços em branco, não sei como adiciona-los, já que já tentei `" ".repeat`, mas o javascript não repete espaços dessa forma.

```js
function escada(numeroDegraus) {
  var degrausEscada = [];
  var comparacao = numeroDegraus;
  for (let i = 1; i <= numeroDegraus; i++) {
    var degraus = "#".repeat(i);
    degrausEscada.push(degraus);
  }
  return degrausEscada;
}

console.log(escada(5));
```

Comment: "*já que já tentei " ".repeat, mas o javascript não repete espaços dessa forma*", não? Eu testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Ele repete apenas um espaço, diferentemente do solicitado na questão, que quando passado um valor 5, teria que no primeiro espaço do array repetir 4 espaços e um #, e assim ir diminuindo até o 0 enquanto que o # iria aumentando até chegar a 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá! Então se você não pode usar outra função, use a mesma.
Considerando que você precisa printar um espaço suficiente para preencher a lacuna que existirá antes, portanto, é os degraus - a posição que está (*i*)

```js
function escada(numeroDegraus) {
  var degrausEscada = [];
  var comparacao = numeroDegraus;
  for (let i = 1; i <= numeroDegraus; i++) {
    var degraus = " ".repeat(numeroDegraus-i)+"#".repeat(i);
    degrausEscada.push(degraus);
  }
  return degrausEscada;
}

console.log(escada(5));
```

Answer (score 3):

Um `padStart` pode te ajudar:

```js
function escada(numeroDegraus) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= numeroDegraus; i++) {
    console.log('#'.repeat(i).padStart(numeroDegraus, ' '));
  }
}

escada(5);
```

Outra opção sem o `repeat` e `padStart`:

```js
var numeroDegraus = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < numeroDegraus; i++) {
    var temp = [];

    // Inclui os espaços primeiro
    let k = 0;
    for (; k < numeroDegraus - (i + 1); k++) {
        temp.push(' ');
    }

    for (; k < numeroDegraus; k++) {
        temp.push('#');
    }

    console.log(temp.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Então, o site o qual estou fazendo o curso, não aceita métodos que não foram ensinados, ou seja, teria que tentar fazer tudo usando o if, for, repeat, push e mais algumas, mas a sua funcionou perfeitamente da forma que ele pede.

Comment: @DouglasMorais Você pode criar as funções `repeat` e `padStart` para seguir as regras do exercício. Para isto dê uma olhada em suas respectivas polyfills. Outra alternativa é utilizar esta ideia e escrever com estas funções supracitadas

Comment: @DouglasMorais adicionado uma outra opção sem o `repeat` e `padStart`. Espero que ajude ;)